# How to invest in Vanguard index fund for non-us citizen from overseas

Tags: united-states, banking, vanguard

How can I open Vanguard's account if I don't live in the US and non-US resident.

Vanguard's ETF is not an option as it involves other factors such as currency exchange, people perception.

If I go to an US vacation , I would be able to open a bank account and have an address, two things that Vanguard needs to open up an account. Would this satisfy the requirement.

Has non US resident + non US citizen done it before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Vanguard [do not](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/LiteratureRequest?FW_Activity=FindLiteratureActivity&FW_Event=specialnotice) allow non-residents opening accounts with them. You can buy their ETFs/funds through a broker on a open market, but not directly through them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to open an account and think of the most effective way to do so. Move to america to study etc, that would tick all the boxes? And then I can keep the account, right?

Comment: @Code_So1dier no, once you stop being US resident they will ask  you to move to their non-resident operation, as it says in the link. You'll go to study in the US just to open an account with Vanguard? That's a bit extreme. There are other brokerage providers in the world, some may even be in your own home country.